# Making AC_ARG_WITH affect gcc invocation for subsequent AC_CHECK_HEADERS

Tags: c, readline, autotools

I have a program that defaults to using the readline library (unless the user specifically disables it using `--without-readline`).  The user can also specify an alternate location for the readline headers and library using `--with-readline=`, e.g., `--with-readline=/usr/local`.

Of course, just because the user didn't disable readline or specified an alternate location means that the readline headers and library actually exist on the system (or where the user claims they do), so I want to check for the actual presence of readline if it's not disabled.

I'm following the last example [here](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/External-Software.html#External-Software) for using `AC_ARG_WITH`, but then later on in my `configure.ac` file, I do:

```
AC_CHECK_HEADERS([readline/readline.h readline/history.h])

# ...

AC_SEARCH_LIBS([readline],[readline])
```

However, giving:

```
./configure --with-readline=/usr/local
```

results in:

```
checking readline/readline.h usability... no
checking readline/readline.h presence... no
checking for readline/readline.h... no
checking readline/history.h usability... no
checking readline/history.h presence... no
checking for readline/history.h... no
```

Looking at `config.log`:

```
configure:6517: checking readline/readline.h usability
configure:6517: gcc -std=gnu99 -std=gnu99 -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
conftest.c:80:31: error: readline/readline.h: No such file or directory
```

The invocation of `gcc` does *not* have `-I/usr/local/include` so of *course* it doesn't find it.

So the question is: how do I get `configure` to invoke `gcc` by adding `-I/usr/local/include` (or wherever the user specifies) when it does `AC_CHECK_HEADERS` and `AC_SEARCH_LIBS`?

---

I did try explicitly augmenting `CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` myself (as I've seen some `configure.ac` files do):

```
AC_ARG_WITH([readline],
  AS_HELP_STRING([--without-readline], [disable support for readline]),
  [],
  [with_readline=yes]
)
AS_IF([test x$with_readline = xyes],
  [
    AC_DEFINE([WITH_READLINE], [1],
      [Define to 1 if readline support is enabled.])
    CFLAGS="-I${withval} ${CFLAGS}"
    LDFLAGS="-L${withval} ${LDFLAGS}"
  ]
)
```

but that didn't help.

---

FYI:

autoconf version = 2.69
automake version = 1.16.1

Comment: Try `CPPFLAGS="-I${withval} ${CPPFLAGS}"` instead of CFLAGS.

Comment: @zwol The `gcc` invocation is unchanged so it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I figured it out. There were three mistakes:

1. The line *should* have been:

   ```
   AS_IF([test x$with_readline != xno],
   ```

   If the user sets a path, then `with_readline` is that path, e.g., `/usr/local`, so it does *not* = `xyes`. Indeed, the GNU example shows it this way. (I'm not sure how I got it wrong here.)
2. The setting of the flags should happen *only* when the user gives an `=value`, i.e., does *not* equal `xyes`:

   ```
   AS_IF([test x$withval != xyes],
     [
       CPPFLAGS="-I${withval}/include ${CPPFLAGS}"
       LDFLAGS="-L${withval}/lib ${LDFLAGS}"
     ]
   )
   ```
3. As shown above, I also forgot to add the `/include` and `/lib` after `{withval}`.